# Unity DirectoryInfo not working in OSX standalone build

Tags: unity, image, file, importing

So I'm building an application in unity which I hope to use at a market day coming up soon at my school (it's not a game, it's basically like a checkout app, kind of...) Anyway, I'd like to be able to import images from the app and to have the option to change them while the app is running. Currently I have the images in a folder and I'm using DirectoryInfo to get the contents of that folder and load the images. Works like a dream inside the editor but as soon as I build the app (on OSX), everything is blank. Other people seem to have similar issues but I'm a little unsure as to how they fixed it. Could someone please help me, this is kind of urgent!